# Asp.net Core UseExceptionHandler not working POST request

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In my .Net Core 2.0 application i have implemented **UseExceptionHandler** to handle exceptions globally. But redirection only works for GET method and POST method always return **Status Code: 404; Not Found**

Here is my Startup.cs Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/v1/Error");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/v1/Error");
        }

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/[]virtualDir]/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
        });
    }
```

And Error controller is

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly IErrorLoggerService _errorLoggerService;

    public ErrorController(IErrorLoggerService errorLoggerService)
    {
        _errorLoggerService= errorLoggerService;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Get the details of the exception that occurred
        var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var errorLog = new ErrorLog();

        if (exceptionFeature != null)
        {
            // Get which route the exception occurred at
            var routeWhereExceptionOccurred = exceptionFeature.Path;

            // Get the exception that occurred
            var exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;

            // TODO: save exception in db
            errorLog = new ErrorLog
            {
                Application = routeWhereExceptionOccurred,
                Source = exceptionThatOccurred.Source,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                Host = exceptionThatOccurred.InnerException?.ToString(),
                Type = exceptionThatOccurred.Message,
                Detail = exceptionThatOccurred.StackTrace
            };
            _errorLoggerService.Save(errorLog);
            return Json(errorLog);
        }

        return Json(errorLog);
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configuring-a-custom-exception-handling-page):

> In an MVC app, don't decorate the error handler action method with HTTP method attributes, such as HttpGet. Explicit verbs prevent some requests from reaching the method. Allow anonymous access to the method so that unauthenticated users are able to receive the error view.

So, your mistake is *probably* in `HttpGet` attribute. Don't use it, instead follow the documentation:

```
[Route("")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a `RouteAttribute`? Or have you tried to use `MapRoute` when configuring Mvc?

Comment: i m not sure about this, do we need this in .Net Core?

Comment: @AnilD what error did you get without `HttpGet`? I made a test with `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version 3.0, it works without `HttpGet`.

Comment: i m using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 2.4`, getting "Failed to load API definition."

Comment: Exact error "Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0"

Comment: Even after updating to `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 3.0` still getting same error

Comment: Using `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)]` make it working but not sure how good this approach is...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the `[HttpGet]` from the Error method because it is what's causing the unnecessary restriction.

```
//[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Minimal APIs, you should use the Map method instead of MapGet. Here's an example.

```
public override void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
{
   app.Map(Routes.V1.Errors.Dev, (HttpContext context) =>
   {  
      var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!;

      return Results.Problem(detail: ex.Error.StackTrace, title: ex.Error.Message, statusCode: StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);

   }).ExcludeFromDescription();
}
```

Find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0).